# Relation not loaded when using column constraint in find

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a somewhat strange problem with Eloquent. Let me give you the code first and then explain:

```
$article = Article::with('comment.reply')->find($id)->toJSON();
```

This query does what it is supposed to do. It loads the data from the articles table, then loads all comments from the comments table and then all replies from the replies table and then spits everything out in JSON. Everything's great.

```
$article = Article::with('comment.reply')->find($id, array('short_title'))->toJSON();
```

Theoretically this query should do the exact same thing with the limitation that only short_title is being loaded from the articles table, right? Guess again. What happens now is that the short title is being loaded, the comments table gets queried but somehow magically returns an empty result and the replies table is completely ignored.

Do I have the wrong expectations or am I doing something wrong here? The relationships are relatively simple, articles->hasMany('comments') and comments->hasMany('replies').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't select the keys, and those are needed for Eloquent to properly build up the Collection.
So basically do this:

```
$article = Article::with('comment.reply')->find($id, array('id', 'short_title'))->toJSON();
```

Should you query also loaded relations you will need to select parent key (article_id, comment_id etc) as well

Comment: Thanks man! This totally did the trick. I was under the impression that the key was already being set via find().